# Solution of inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

## Question:

$x$ and $y$ are different integers and both $x$ and $y$ are greater than $0$. If  $x^2-y^2<8$ and $x+y>3$, what is the maximum value of $x$?

### My solution:

I used plugged in number method, and found for $x=4$ and $y=3$, $4^2-3^2=7$ and $4+3=7$, satisfies both equations. but, if $x=5$ and $y=4$, values doesn't satisfy first equation. hence, maximum possible value of $x= 4$.

#### Is there any other easy way than this to solve this problem?

Comment: The solution is unbounded. Take $x=y=1$ million, and the conditions will still be satisfied!

Comment: Your solution works if we're limited to integers, and with $x \neq y$. If either of those restrictions are lifted, then you can get $y$ as high as you want.

Comment: That's correct, i missed this point. so, if  x≠y condition is satisfied, is my approach correct?

Comment: First, you ask for a maximum value of $y$ and find the maximum possible value of $x$. As second, you always choose $y$ to be $x-1$ (right, but can you say why?). I also suggest to look down at my solution. (maybe you didn't wrote everything, but from my point of view, you need to provide more arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y) < 8 $, and $x+y > 3$ we know $x-y<2$.

So, if there is a additional condititon  $x \neq y$ (I will asume that, also that $x>y$), then $x=1+y$.

So $(y+1)^2 - y^2 < 8$, so $2y+1<8 $, and maximum of $y$ is $3$.

Without the condition $x \neq y$ the value of $y$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

There is no maximum value of $y$:

Let $y$ be any integer with $y\ge3$, and let $x=y-1$.

Then $x^2-y^2<0<8$, and $x+y=2y-1\ge5>3$.

Comment: I added a condition $x>y$ to make the answer make sense ( $ 0<y<x $). Under that conditions, the values of $y$ is really bounded.